# Table Views & the Data Model for Swift example

Tags: ios, swift

I study Swift for the week and trying to create categories in my app.

I'm looking for the example that contains separation from categories to subcategories. 
I have found an old Apple documentation about my issue, but **it's on Objective-C.**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html

I would be very grateful if you would help me found/code an example project.

**example:**
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbepV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like what you want to do is pretty basic. Following the traditional MVC pattern you can create a struct for categories, and sub catagories.

You'll also be using multiple table view controller so I would recommend using generic table view controller so it's more reusable.

One of my favorite iOS developer did a talk on generic tableview controller and I think it's worth watching. Here's the link:
https://realm.io/news/tryswift-chris-eidhof-table-view-controllers-swift/

Sorry if this is not what you're looking for.